How can I tell Pyyaml to convert PosixPath to str in yaml.dump?
I understand that YAML allows you to represent arbitrary data using tags. I would like to convert a PosixPath to a str instead of representing it as a !!pathlib.PosixPath. How can I tell pyyaml to convert PosixPath to str every time it encounters the type?

To represent pathlib instances as generic strings, use the tag:yaml.org,2002:str scalar tag (see the spec section 10.1.1.3).
To add this representer for default dumpers:
import pathlib
import yaml.dumper

data = {"me": pathlib.Path("/home/xaviersjs")}

def path_representer(dumper, obj):
    return dumper.represent_scalar("tag:yaml.org,2002:str", str(obj))

for dumper_name in yaml.dumper.__all__:
    Dumper = getattr(yaml.dumper, dumper_name)
    yaml.add_representer(
        type(pathlib.Path()),
        path_representer,
        Dumper,
    )

print(yaml.dump(data))
print(yaml.safe_dump(data))

Note that this globally modifies the default behavior of PyYAML. That might be acceptable if you're doing this in an application, but it is unacceptable for a library to modify global mutable state.
If you're a library, make your own patched dumper type and use it explicitly, don't modify the global mutable state of PyYAML itself:
import pathlib
import yaml.dumper

data = {"me": pathlib.Path("/home/xaviersjs")}

def path_representer(dumper, obj):
    return dumper.represent_scalar("tag:yaml.org,2002:str", str(obj))

class MyDumper(yaml.dumper.SafeDumper):
    pass

yaml.add_representer(
    type(pathlib.Path()),
    path_representer,
    MyDumper,
)

print("patched:", yaml.dump(data, Dumper=MyDumper))
print("default:", yaml.dump(data))


Even in an application, there might be other parts of that application you're not aware of that use PyYAML. I would always recommend to use a subclass.

This works great, thanks! Instead of having path_representer a separate function, I just dropped a lambda into the add_representer call and that worked too.
